# informatica domain installed successful but not repository service in windows8

Tags: informatica

I have successfully installed informatica domain but not able to create Repository service.

Pl help me

It is showing 'not able to connect database on xe server'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection string for your repository database when you are creating the repository service. If you are using Oracle XE, then the connection string should be `<hostname>/<service name>`. For example, `localhost/XE`.